# Javac classpath (.java file)

Tags: java

I want to compile a java file from the command line using this command: `javac -cp C:/Java myPgm.java` but it keeps saying that

```
javac: file not found: myPgm.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

any help please? ;)[image]

Comment: Well either your filepath is wrong or it's the space in `C:/Java myPgm.java`. Though I have to say `Java myPgm.java` sounds like a weird filename. Did you mean `C:/Java/myPgm.java` or something? If this doesn't work use `-help` for a list of possible options.

Comment: I've just uploaded the photo for the directory. hope it helps for you to answer my question... thanks :)

Comment: It looks like the answer was what I wrote in my comment above. You're missing the second `/`. It's `C:/Java/myPgm.java` whereas you wrote `C:/Java myPgm.java`.

Comment: still the same error..

Comment: i think it needs javac [option] [arguement] [sourefile] like this. i think the code you gave me is missing the [sourcefile] section since there are only three part of the code (javac -cp C:\Java\myPgm.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the following code in the terminal to compile the java source code

> `javac C:/Java/myPgm.java`

then to execute the code

> `java theClassNameOfTheJavaFile`

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Comment: Please be kind enough to accept the answer ( by ticking the correct at the left ), so that others who are having the same question may find this answer as correct.

Comment: Sure thing. (I am new to Stack overflow so I didn't knew it) thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

go to your current directory then 
type

javac myPgm.java
 then

java myPgm

if program inside package then

javac -d . myPgm.java

and then

java package_name.myPgm